# How to find app path automatically

Tags: vb.net

How can i find application path automatically?

For example, if in my computer  "**FILEexample.exe**" is in "**c: Windows/FILEexample.exe**"
While in my friend's computer "**FILEexample.exe**" is in "**D:/Folder1/FILEexample.exe**"

I want to know how to find that path dynamically.

Comment: By creating a program that does that for you. Jokes aside, please explain what you have tried so far, with what do you want to create it. And also SO is not a free coding service nor a tutorial website. First attempt the problem yourself and when you face issues, come back and post a question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the path your application was started from, use:
[Application.StartupPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx)